# Can someone explain D language template shorthand form?

Tags: d

I have a professor that wrote all his examples for D templates in shorthand:

```
T exec(alias f,T)(T t) {
    return f(t);
}
```

I can't find any examples that explain what this means. Can someone here explain it?

Comment: Dang, you have a prof who writes in D?! coool!

Comment: Yes, and he's written a long paper he had us read advocating the teaching of D as an introductory course (right now they teach C# first).

Comment: I like it so far, but it's a little hard to get used to the syntax.

Comment: Oh, and the instructor is on the C++ standards committee, so I think that says a lot.

Comment: Another shorthand template syntax you'll probably see that might look weird is, for example, to!int("10");. If there's only one simple (just one word) template argument, you don't have to put parenthesis around it. to!int("10") is the same as to!(int)("10").

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In a function template, the first set of parens hold the template arguments and the second set holds the function arguments.

http://dlang.org/template.html#function-templates

You could rewrite that as:

```
template exec(alias f, T) {
    T exec(T t) {
         return f(t);
    }
}
```

At the usage point, if a template member has the same name as the template itself, you don't have to write it twice. This is called the eponymous trick. http://www.bing.com/search?q=eponymous+trick+d+programming+language&qs=n&form=QBRE&pq=eponymous+trick+d+programming+languag&sc=0-0&sp=-1&sk=

Though most D code I've seen uses the shorter format - the long template syntax is pretty rare for functions, classes, or structs, which can do it too: struct Foo(T) { } is a struct template with argument T.

The arguments themselves in this exec template are "alias f", which is any symbol you decide to pass it, e.g., a function or variable name, and "T", just any generic type. The repeated T are references to that type.

At the usage point, you'll most likely see it like this:

```
int foo(int a) { return a; } // just a regular function
exec!(foo)(10); // instantiates the template with arguments (foo, int), and then calls the function.
```

The second template argument here is figured out implicitly by the function arguments. This is very common with function templates: a lot of the template arguments are implicit so you rarely see them written out. You might see this referenced in D discussions as "IFTI", which means "implicit function template instantiation".

Comment: If you want to learn more about D templates: http://ddili.org/ders/d.en/templates.html https://github.com/PhilippeSigaud/D-templates-tutorial/blob/master/dtemplates.pdf

Answer (score 4):

```
T exec(alias f,T)(T t) {
    return f(t);
}
```

Here’s a shorthand template function. The « normal way » to write it is:

```
template exec(alias f, T) {
    T exec(T t) {
        return f(t);
    }
}
```

In `D`, if a symbol in a template scope has the same name the template itself has, you can use it as the template (it’s sorta an alias).

Then, the `alias` template parameter means that it can be anything – any **symbol**. Here, it can be a delegate, a function, a fonctor, anything. It could even be a string if your teacher used the `std.functional.unaryFun`.

The `T` parameter, like in C++, is just a type symbol.

That function just applies a functor. Here’s a strongest version :

https://github.com/D-Programming-Language/phobos/blob/master/std/functional.d#L39

Comment: It's "functor," not "fonctor." The "func" is from function.